# Do wrapping diagonals on Word Searches contain all letters?

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Given an example, 3x3 word search grid as follows:

$\begin{bmatrix}A & B & C\\D & E & F\\G & H & I\end{bmatrix}$

We use a zero-based index and elements are identified by their $(row, column)$. A wrapping, main diagonal starting at $(0,0)$ will contain $[A, E, I]$ before wrapping back to the letter $A$. Another wrapping diagonal starting at $(0, 1)$ contains $[B, F, G]$. Thus, wrapping is defined such that when the index goes beyond the extent of a dimension, it is "wrapped" back to the first index.

Consider a $m\times n$ word search grid where $m \ne n$. **Do *all* wrapping diagonals for these grids contain all letters of the word search?**

Example:

$\begin{bmatrix}A & B & C\\D & E & F\\G & H & I\\J & K & L\end{bmatrix}$

The wrapping, main diagonal starting at $(0,0)$ contains $[A, E, I, J, B, F, G, K, C, D, H, L]$ before wrapping back to $A$. This diagonal contains all the letters of the word search grid or it traverses and visits all elements.

Comment: Try 2 x 4, then 3 x 6, then 3 x 5, then 4 x 6.  Inspired by these ezamples, suggest the general result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if $m$ and $n$ are coprime. Indeed, we can reformulate your question using group theory. Each element in the matrix can be viewed as an element of $\mathbb Z_m \oplus \mathbb Z_n$, and a wrapping diagonal can be viewed as an enumeration of the subgroup generated by $(1, 1)$. We want to know when $\langle (1, 1) \rangle = \mathbb Z_m \oplus \mathbb Z_n$. Now since:
$$
|(1, 1)| = \text{lcm}(|1|, |1|) = \text{lcm}(m, n) = \frac{mn}{\gcd(m, n)}
$$
and since $|\mathbb Z_m \oplus \mathbb Z_n| = mn$, it follows that $\langle (1, 1) \rangle = \mathbb Z_m \oplus \mathbb Z_n$ iff $\gcd(m, n) = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - provided m and n are not 0 and your wrapping implementation is similar to that used in computing a determinant.

Comment: No, not as I understand the question. Try $(m,n)=(2,4)$, for instance.